# Call function on ng-click (cellTemplate)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem with my angular grid.

This is my code:

```
cellTemplate: '<div id="btn_excluir" ng-click="grid.appScope.doSomething()" class="btn primary glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></div> <div class="btn primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onclick="alert();"></div>'

vm.doSomething = function() {
    alert("ALERT!");
 }
```

I would like to call the function doSomething() but this never works...

Do you have any ideia?

Thanks!

Comment: did you use $compiler?

Comment: No, I didn't used $compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you have the issue with naming so the function is not called.

Another thing is, when you add html like this, you need to trigger Angular to actually register this directives you've added as javascript. Thats because when you write directly angular directives in html, when app will start running, it will go through the HTML template and look for that directives like ng-click and convert them into html code.

If you add html code manually in angular during the run of the app, you will need to trigger this compilation manually.

That's that compile Suren was talking about.

One more thing: When I look at your code, it looks like you could easily do this in the template. Im not sure what are you trying to do, but its probably doable better way, where you don't have to do this manual compile etc.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Takáč! Can you please explain me how to do this: One more thing: When I look at your code, it looks like you could easily do this in the template. Im not sure what are you trying to do, but its probably doable better way, where you don't have to do this manual compile etc.

Comment: Can you explain why are you adding this buttons? If Ill get what are you trying to build Ill be able to probably help you with some more elegant solution. Based on what are you adding this buttons? Do you need to remove them in some cases? Are you also adding some another data, or just buttons?

Comment: Nice!
I have a grid, and the last column of the grid is "ACTIONS". In this column I'll have a button to delete and edit the content of the row.

Comment: How are you rendering the grid? In html using ng-repeat?

Comment: Yes, I'm rendering using ng-repeat

Comment: So why you don't add into that rows buttons directly as part of ng-repeat? You don't need to add it manually in js. In this case, that ng-click will work.

Comment: Great solution friend! I'll try it! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `ng-click="doSomething()"`  instead of your ng-click `ng-click="grid.appScope.doSomething()"`

and also let me know did you use [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) while add html with your cell template.

> $compile means : Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function

Comment: No, I don't used $compiler =/
I'm new to angular... And don't know what is this...

Comment: did you try my answer? try it if it not work then  see this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Yeah... I'll do this =)

Answer (score 0):

Here the Solution

```
  cellTemplate: '<div id="btn_excluir" ng-click="grid.appScope.doSomething()" class="btn primary glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></div> <div class="btn primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onclick="alert();"></div>'

     var vm = this;
     vm.gridOptions.appScopeProvider = vm;
     vm.doSomething = function () {
        alert("ALERT!");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.